# Is it possible to somehow get this randomly generated key for my site and access the SQL?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, security, encryption

I have a php/js site where the information is encoded and put into the database. The encryption key for the information is randomly generated, then given back to the users after they send a post through a form. The encryption key is not stored in my database at all. A seperate, randomly generated, ID is formed and stored in the database, used to lookup the item itself before deciphering it.

My question is, is it possible at all to look through the logs and find information that would reveal the key? I am trying to make it impossible to read any of the SQL data without either being the person who has the code (who can do whatever he wants with it), or by a brute force attack (unavoidable if someone gets my SQL database)?

Just to re-iterate my steps:

1. User sends information through POST
2. php file generates random ID and access key. The data is encrypted with the access key then put in the php database with the ID as the PRIMARY KEY.
3. php file echos just the random ID and the access key.
4. website uses jQuery to create a link from the key and *mysite.com?i=cYFogD3Se8RkLSE1CA* [9 digit A-Ba-b09 = ID][9 digit A-Ba-b09 = key]

Is there any possibility if someone had access to my server that can read the information? I want it to be information for me to read the messages myself. The information has to be decodable, it can't be a one way encoding.

Comment: From what you have described, it appears that only the client has the key to decrypt the data and the server relys on this being send by the client to the server. How is it being store on the client? What happens if it gets deleted? If that happens no one will be able to read the data. You are also sending the encryption key through the net in the clear - this is a massive vulnerablity in and of itself.

Comment: If someone hacks your server they can easily just setup a logger to log all POST/GET data, which would include data before it is encrypted, not to mention any submittal of keys. What you want it public key cryptography, where the user supplies public key which you store on server and use to encrypt the the data if any. Then user on their end can decrypt the data with their private key. You want this over SSL/TLS of course. If the user can encrypt the data prior to sending to server even safer.

Comment: Ok, so make the key generation client side instead of server side? That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Actually wait, this is not possible because I want the site to work when javascript is disabled.

Is there anyway to know if a post/get hack has been implemented in my server?

Comment: A browser cannot do this without running scripts. You still have the problem that the client needs to persist the key in order to retrieve the data. If you are in a position to say, what kind of data is this that needs this level of protection?

Comment: I do not know what data might need the encryption. I am making a website for fun where people can encrypt messages and send them to each other. The messages could be social security numbers, bank access codes, or other personal information. The website is designed for phones.

Comment: I wish you had told us the one-time nature of the data and your plans to delete on first access. It would have saved me some wasted time and allowed me to provide you with a more focused and complete answer the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with some basic definitions:

**Code** Protecting data by translating it to another language, usually a private language. English translated to Spanish is encoded but its not very secure since many people understand Spanish.

**Cipher** Protecting data by scrambling it up using a key. A letter substitution cipher first documented by Julius Caesar is an example of this. Modern techniques involve mathematical manipulation of binary data using prime numbers. The best techniques use asymmetric keys; the key that is used to encipher the data cannot decipher it, a different key is needed. This allows the public key to be published and is the basis of SSL browser communication.

**Encryption** Protecting data by *encoding* and/or *enciphering* it.

All of these terms are often used interchangeably but they are different and the differences are sometimes important. What you are trying to do is to protect the data by a cipher.

If the data is "in clear" then if it is intercepted it is lost. If it is enciphered, then both the data and the key need to be intercepted. If it is enciphered and encoded, then the data, the key and the code need to be intercepted.

Where is your data vulnerable?

1. The most vulnerable place for any data is when it is in clear the personal possession of somebody, on a storage device (USB, CD, piece of paper) or inside their head since that person is vulnerable to inducement or coercion. This is the foundation of Wikileaks - people who are trusted with in confidence information are induced to betray that confidence - the ethics of this I leave to your individual consciences.
2. When it is in transit between the client and the server and vice versa. Except for data of national security importance the SSL method of encryption should be adequate.
3. When it is in memory in your program. The source code of your program is the best place to store your keys, however, they themselves need to be stored encrypted with a password that you enter each time your program runs (best), that is entered when you compile and publish or that is embedded in your code (worst). Unless you have a very good reason one key should be adequate; not one per user. You should also keep in-memory data encrypted except when you actually need it and you should use any in-memory in-clear data structures immediately and destroy them as soon as you are finished with them. The key has to be stored somewhere or else the data is irrecoverable. But consider, who has access to the source code (including backups and superseded versions) and how can you check for backdoors or trojans?
4. When it is in transit between your program's machine and the data store. If you only send encrypted data between the program and the data store and DO NOT store the key in the data store this should be OK.
5. When it is stored in the data store. Ditto.

Do not overlook physical security, quite often the easiest way to steal data is to walk up to the server and copy the hard drive. Many companies (and sadly defence/security forces) spend millions on on-line data security and then put their data in a room with *no* lock. They also have access protocols that a 10 year old child could circumvent.

You now have lovely encrypted data - how are you going to stop your program from serving it up in the clear to anyone who asks for it?

This brings us to identification, validation and authorisation. More definitions:

**Identification** A claim made by a person that they are so-and-so. This is usually handled in a computer program by a user name. In physical security applications it is by a person presenting themselves and saying "I am so-and-so"; this can explicitly be by a verbal statement or by presenting an identity document like a passport or implicitly by a guard you know recognising you.

**Validation** This is the proof that a person is who they say they are. In a computer this is the role of the password; more accurately, this proves that they know the person they say they are's password which is the big, massive, huge and insurmountable problem in the whole thing. In physical security it is by comparing physical metrics (appearance, height etc) as documented in a trusted document (like a passport) against the claim; you need to have protocols in place to ensure that you can trust the document. Incidentally, this is the main cause of problems with face recognition technology to identify bad guys – it uses a validation technique to try and identify someone. “This guy looks like Bad Guy #1”; guess what? So do a lot of people in a population of 7 billion.

**Authorisation** Once a person has been identified and validated they are then given authorisation to do certain things and go to certain places. They may be given a temporary identification document for this; think of a visitor id badge or a cookie. Depending on where they go they may be required to reidentify and revalidate themselves; think of a bank’s website; you identify and validate yourself to see your bank accounts and you do it again to make transfers or payments.

By and large, this is the weakest part of any computer security system; it is hard for me to steal you data, it is far easier for me to steal your identity and have the data given to me.

In your case, this is probably not your concern, providing that you do the normal thing of allowing the user to set, change and retrieve their password in the normal commercial manner, you have probably done all you can.

Remember, data security is a trade off between security on the one hand and trust and usability on the other. Make things too hard (like high complexity passwords for low value data) and you compromise the whole system (because people are people and they *write them down*).

Like everything in computers – users are a problem!

**Why are you protecting this data, and what are you willing to spend to do so?**

This is a classic risk management question. In effect, you need to consider the adverse consequences of losing this data, the risk of this happening with your present level of safeguards and if the reduction in risk that additional safeguards will cost is worth it.

Losing the data can mean any or all of:

1. Having it made public
2. Having if fall into the wrong person’s hands
3. Having it destroyed maliciously or accidently. (Backup, people!)
4. Having it changed. If you know it has been changed this is equivalent to losing it; if you don’t this can be much, much worse since you may be acting on false data.

This type of thinking is what leads to the classification of data in defence and government into Top Secret, Secret, Restricted and Unrestricted (Australian classifications). The human element intervenes again here; due to the nature of bureaucracy there is no incentive to give a document a low classification and plenty of disincentive; so documents are routinely over-classified. This means that because many documents with a Restricted classification need to be distributed to people who don’t have the appropriate clearance simply to make the damn thing work, this is what happens.

You can think of this as a hierarchy as well; my personal way of thinking about it is:

1. **Defence of the Realm** Compromise will have serious adverse consequences for the strategic survival of my country/corporation/family whatever level you are thinking about.
2. **Life and Death** Compromise will put someone’s life or health in danger.
3. **Financial** Compromise will allow someone to have money/car/boat/space shuttle stolen.
4. **Commercial** Compromise will cause loss of future financial gain.
5. **Humiliating** Compromise will cause embarrassment. Of course, if you are a politician this is probably No 1.
6. **Personal** These are details that you would rather not have released but aren’t particularly earth shaking. I would put my personal medical history in here but, the impact of contravening privacy laws may push it up to Humiliating (if people find out) or Financial (if you get sued or prosecuted).
7. **Private** This is stuff that is nobody else’s business but doesn’t actually hurt you if they find out.
8. **Public** Print it in the paper for all anyone cares.

Irrespective of the level, you don’t want any of this data lost or changed but if it is, you need to know that this has happened. For the Nazi’s, having their Enigma cipher broken was bad; not knowing it had happened was catastrophic.

In the comments below, I have been asked to describe best practice. This is impossible without knowing the risk of the data (and risk tolerance of the organisation). Spending too much on data security is as bad as spending too little.

Comment: Love your answer. I have always thought of the "identification + validation" part as **authentication** and then **authorization** is a separate step. (Now that we know who you are, what are you allowed to do?) But you have titled the authorization part with "authentication", which seems incorrect. Also, could you address the best way to keep his database secure in addition to physical security--let's say someone's goal IS to copy the data from his database. How should he try to guard against that?

Comment: @ErikE - Thanks, you are absolutely right - I have fixed my typo.

Comment: @ErikE - With respect to how to do it; this is a how long is a piece of string or more precisely how big his budget is question. If you have enogh resorces you can always get the data - is he prepared for a physical attack from a Special Operations force? I will expand my answer along these lines.

Comment: I added my own perspective. :)

Comment: Thank you. You really taught me a lot about security with this post. I will use some of this information on my website for others to read. The website I am making for fun, and the back end only accessible by me. The information isn't for a specific group of people, but the general populace. Whether you're sharing an SSN number, a private message you don't want your mom to read, or anything. You write a message, it's encrypted and a link is given. The first person who visits that link can see the message, and then it is deleted from the database. There is no login or any sort of identification.

Comment: OK, I understand - I will post another answer

Comment: How many keys can a brute force attacker go through per second if he has the data stored on his computer? Right now my cipher password length of 9 allows for 13 quadrillion possible combinations.

Answer (score 2):

I like your system of the URL containing the decryption key, so that not even you, without having data available only on the user's computer, will be able to access.

I still see a few gotchas in this.

1. URLs are often saved in web server logs. If you're logging to disk, and they get the disk, then they get the keys.
2. If the attacker has access to your database, he may have enough access to your system to secretly install software that logs the URLs. He could even do something as prosaic as turn logging back on.
3. The person visiting your site will have the URL bookmarked at least (otherwise it is useless to him) and it will likely appear in his browser history. Normally, bookmarks and history are not considered secure data. Thus, an attacker to a user's computer (either by sitting down directly or if the computer is compromised by malware) can access the data as well. If the payload is desirable enough, someone could create a virus or malware that specifically mines for your static authentication token, and could achieve a reasonable hit rate. The URLs could be available to browser plugins, even, or other applications acting under a seemingly reasonable guise of "import your bookmarks now".

So it seems to me that the best security is then for the client to not just have the bookmark (which, while it is information, it is not kept in anyone's head so can be considered "something he has"), but also for him to have to present "something he knows", too. So encrypt with his password, too, and don't save the password. When he presents the URL, ask for a password, and then decrypt with both (serially or in combination) and the data is secure.

Finally, I know that Google's two-factor authentication can be used by third parties (for example, I use it with Dropbox). This creates another "something you have" by requiring the person accessing the resource to have his cell phone, or nothing. Yes, there is recourse if you lose your cell phone, but it usually involves another phone number, or a special Google-supplied one-time long password that has been printed out and stashed in one's wallet.

Comment: Thank you. A few things I did not mention in the original post:

**1:** The data is deleted when viewed. So a URL history will not work since the data will have been destroyed when read.
**2:** There is no Login system of any sort. The only ID is the ID of the database entry, and the Cipher (which is not stored in the databse), in order to preserve the anonymity of the information in case it is compromised.
**3:** The information could be anything, since it's made for public use. SSN numbers, credit cards, or secret love letters to your mistress.

Comment: Now how would an attacker get access to the read/write permissions on my webserver, access the settings, or access to the SQL database (besides SQL injection)?

Comment: You were asking about how to make your private data secure from hackers. That is a compromised system scenario. So if the attackers own your system, why not your web server too? SQL Server does have `xp_cmdshell` you know!

Answer (score 1):

**First and most importantly, you need a really good, watertight legal disclaimer.**

**Second, don’t store the user’s data at all.**

Instead when the user submits the data (using SSL), generate a hash of the SessionID and your system’s datetime. Store this hash in your table along with the datetime and get the record ID. Encrypt the user’s data with this hash and generate a URL with the record ID and the data within it and send this back to the user (again using SSL). Security of this URL is now the user’s problem and you no longer have any record of what they sent (make sure it is not logged).

Routinely, delete stale (4h,24h?) records from the database.

When a retrieval request comes in (using SSL) lookup the hash, if it’s not there tell the user the URL is stale. If it is, decrypt the data they sent and send it back (using SSL) and delete the record from your database.

Comment: *First and most importantly, you need a really good, watertight legal disclaimer.* For what? The security of my site? Or the content of the data that is stored on the site?

The Hash thing is a great idea, and I will be implementing it soon. I already delete any records over 24h, and the data already has a datetime stored.

Comment: I use your site to encrypt my bank account. I send it by email. Someone intecepts it and takes my money. Who am I going to sue?

Comment: OK, I will contact a lawyer about having proper legal information on my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets have a little think

1. Use SSL - Data is encrypted
2. Use username/password for authorisation

IF someboby breaks that - you do have a problem with security

Spend the effort on fixing that. Disaster recover is a waste of effort in this case. Just get the base cases correct.